# Postgres width_bucket: function width_bucket(bigint, integer[]) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I run two different queries. This one works well

```
with t(n) as(
    values
           (1),
           (1),
           (1),
           (2),
           (10)
)
select
       width_bucket(n,array[1,3,6,15]) g,
       count(*)
from t
group by g
order by g
```

but when I run this (real) query, it reports error on bucket

```
with data as (
    select
           vendor_id,
           count(distinct pi.id) as cnt
    from payment_invoice_items as pii
    join payment_invoices as pi
        on pii.invoice_id = pi.id
        and pii.deleted_at isnull
    group by vendor_id
)
select
       width_bucket(data.cnt, array[1,10,20,30,40,100,200,400]) as grp,
       count(*)
from data
group by grp
order by grp
```

The `data.cnt` is a one column of integer data. why does this report error?

> [42883] ERROR: function width_bucket(bigint, integer[]) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Thanks

Comment: `The data.cnt is a one column of integer data` No, `COUNT` returns a `BIGINT`, so you will have to explicitly cast it to `INTEGER` in the `width_bucket` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COUNT` function returns type `BIGINT`, not `INTEGER`. Hence the error on that type:

> [42883] ERROR: function width_bucket(bigint, integer[]) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

You will need to cast `COUNT`'s result explicitly to `INTEGER` in order to use it in your function:

```sql
with data as (
    select
           vendor_id,
           count(distinct pi.id) as cnt
    from payment_invoice_items as pii
    join payment_invoices as pi
        on pii.invoice_id = pi.id
        and pii.deleted_at isnull
    group by vendor_id
)
select
       width_bucket(data.cnt::INTEGER, array[1,10,20,30,40,100,200,400]) as grp,
       count(*)
from data
group by grp
order by grp
```